# Guice: Using @Named to create object

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Using Guice, if I have

```
@Inject @Named("light")
Color light;
```

I can use

```
bind(Color.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("light"))
    .toInstance(new Color("white"));
```

to bind it to white color if Color constructor only requires color name.

But how can I do it if Color constructor also requires objects which are created by Guice? For example:

```
@Inject
public Color(ColorSet colorset, String colorName) {...}
```

where colorset is create at runtime by Guice and in not available in configure(){...}.

I would like to do it without:

- creating a class/subclass for each color that I need to inject (like WhiteColor)
- using reflection directly in my code
- changing my classes to use `ColorFactoy factory; factory.get("light");` instead of `@Named("light") Color light;`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The best way to do this is not with a factory but with [`@Provides` methods](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods).  My company uses Guice very, very extensively, and `requestInjection` is always considered a bad idea because it can easily set up a very fragile graph of implicit dependencies.

Here's what it should look like:

```
public class FooModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    // do configuration
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("white")
  Color provideWhiteColor(ColorSet colorSet) {
    return colorSet.white(); // or whatever
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("black")
  Color provideBlackColor(ColorSet colorSet) {
    return colorSet.black(); // or whatever
  }

  // etc
}
```

Comment: This is great idea, probably I can also mix it with Modules.override().with() to reuse them.

Comment: That's helpful - any idea how you can use a Guice injector to get either of the instances? Looking for something like `Guice.createInjector(FooModule).getInstance(Color.class)` but with a specification of "white" or "black"..

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it with @Named, but you should be using binding annotations (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations) anyway.  Then you could say injector.getInstance(Key.get(Color.class, Black.class)) (though I may be missing a generic type specification in there somewhere).  getInstance(...) is overloaded to also take a Key (http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html), not just a class.

Answer (score 5):

You could setup a factory within the module, and request injection on it to fill in the ColorSet.

Module:

```
ColorFactory colorFactory = new ColorFactory();

requestInjection(colorFactory);

bind(Color.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("light")).toInstance(colorFactory.buildColor("white"));
bind(Color.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("dark")).toInstance(colorFactory.buildColor("black"));
```

ColorFactory:

```
public class ColorFactory {

    private ColorSet colorSet;

    public Color buildColor(String color){
        return new Color(colorSet, color);
    }

    @Inject
    public void setColorSet(ColorSet colorSet) {
        this.colorSet = colorSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I read that as you didn't want a subclass of each color (ie: WhiteColor).  Are you looking to reference other colors as well?

Comment: Can you clarify your usage of ColorSet?

Comment: That's just a simplified example of the real situation. There is not a colorset, there is a graph of objects created and connected by guice.

Comment: Are your colors considered immutable?

Comment: No, but does it help if I make them immutable?

Comment: Im not sure... just trying to figure out your architecture.  I'll think about this usage of guice some more and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: I doubt that, but your idea may still be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! They doesn't need to be immutable this way. I can bind named color to injected providers (instead of color instances).

Comment: Cool.  Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 3):

There are few code bases where I have seen the use of injector directly in order fetch certain object.

```
injector.getInstance(Color.class);
```

In this case, you can use the following:

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(Color.class, Names.named("light")));
```